# Are (plant-based) vitamin D₂ supplements as effective as vitamin D₃?

Tags: veganism, nutrition, vitamins-and-minerals, supplements, vitamin-d

Many vegans and non-vegans have low vitamin D levels. Apart from synthesizing it with sunlight, it is possible to ingest it from the diet, but there are no natural, reliable vegan sources of vitamin D, as far as I know.

Vitamin D occurs in two [vitamers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitamer), D₂ and D₃. D₂ occurs, e.g. in mushrooms and alfalfa sprouts. Vegan vitamin D₂ supplements are widely available.

Vitamin D₃ is typically produced from fish, or [lanolin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanolin) (wool fat). (Sheep, being vegan, take up vitamin D₃ by licking their own wool.) Although [vegan D₃ supplements are sold](http://vitashine-d3.com/), they're not as widely available as D₂ supplements.

It is sometimes claimed that vitamin D₂ is not as effective, or also not as bioavailable, as D₃. Is this true? *Is vitamin D₂ less effective than vitamin D₃?*

Comment: I think that "effective" may be a tough part of this question (perhaps too broad?) -- but "bioavailable" is more answerable biologically.

Comment: @Erica, yes, "effective" is hard to answer. For example, one could look at symptoms of vitamin D deficiency, and how good D₂ is at relieving them, compared to D₃.

Comment: Perhaps look for research simply on vitamin D levels, rather than deficiency symptoms (I've been dealing with moderate vitamin D deficiency for _years_ and symptoms/improvements are subtle) -- ideally answers are going to be fairly quantifiable, rather than "I know I always feel better after eating mushrooms than after taking D3 supplements"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vitamin D is often treated generically, sometimes even not specifying the index. According to [this article](http://www.globalhealingcenter.com/natural-health/vitamin-d/), there are five Ds (D1, D2, D3, D4 & D5) and only **D2 (ergocalciferol)** and **D3 (cholecalciferol)** can be used by our bodies.

[This article](http://www.globalhealingcenter.com/natural-health/vitamin-d3-vs-vitamin-d2/) goes further and makes a difference between D2 and D3. D3 is clear winner (my emphasis):

> The majority of studies that compare, and continue to compare, the
>   effects of vitamin D2 and D3 all resonate with one statement:
>   **vitamin D3 is far superior for the human body**. Research over the last ten years has produced an overwhelming amount of evidence that
>   **vitamin D3 is better absorbed and utilized than D2.** Simply put, if you want the best form of vitamin D, choose vitamin D3.
>
> Studies have consistently shown that, functionally, **vitamin D3 is at
>   least 300% more effective than D2**. A review of over 50 vitamin D
>   studies also shows that vitamin D3 offers a noticeable decrease in
>   overall mortality, significantly surpassing D2 in reducing death rates
>   from all causes. Vitamin D3 supplementation has also been shown to
>   maintain serum vitamin D levels in the long run, especially in the
>   winter months when sunlight is scarce.

Also, see references mentioned in the text ([1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24001747), [2](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21735411), [3](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21177785), [4](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23168298)).

[This article](http://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/746941) (*a free account might be required to read it)* goes into more medical details related to D3 vs D2 (its target audience is mostly health professionals):

> Studies indicate that ergocalciferol (vitamin D2) is much less potent
>   and has a shorter duration of action than cholecalciferol.
>
> [...] ergocalciferol potency is less than 30% of that of cholecalciferol and
>   that it has a markedly shorter duration of action.

**Conclusion**

> [...] ergocalciferol (vitamin D2) and cholecalciferol (vitamin D3) are
>   not bioequivalent and should not be considered interchangeable.
>   Although few head-to-head trials exist, based on pharmacokinetic
>   studies and limited clinical evidence, cholecalciferol is preferred
>   over ergocalciferol.

**Recommendation**

> Health professionals should encourage use of cholecalciferol (D3) over
>   ergocalciferol (D2) in all patients without severe renal failure, either as
>   a general supplement or as a treatment for vitamin D deficiency.

**Answer to your question:**

Yes, vitamin D₂ is less effective than vitamin D₃

Comment: Great answer, thanks for that! Following the information provided in your answer, hypothethically speaking, if one were to use a 2000 IU (or  50mcg) D2 supplement and eat some vitamin D fortified foods as well, this should be enough? I am asking because I currently have D2 supplements and would like to know whether to just ditch them or I can keep on using them and buy vegan D3 the next time.

Comment: @AlexanderRossa - if you are worried about vitamin D levels, you can easily take a [vitamin D blood test](https://labtestsonline.org/understanding/analytes/vitamin-d/tab/test/). It is one of the [tests recommended for vegans](http://renegadehealth.com/blog/2011/08/25/top-10-blood-tests-for-vegetarians-and-vegans). However, vitamin D deficiency can be caused by many other factors, as explained in [this article](http://www.webmd.com/diet/guide/vitamin-d-deficiency): limited exposure to sunlight, dark skin, kidneys not working properly, absorbing problems etc.

Comment: Is it possible to make up for the difference by simply taking more D2?

Comment: @AlexHall - I cannot find an exact answer to your question, but taking D3 is clearly recommended ([source](https://saveourbones.com/the-huge-difference-between-vitamins-d3-and-d2-and-why-you-should-never-take-d2/)]. This article says that in some cases, there is a small difference between efficient dozes and toxic ones for D2, so higher doses are risky. So, better use D3.